# Apache POI Excel Formula entering @ Symbols where they don't belong

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am having an issue where the formula that I am using is very specific. When entering the formula in via the programming, I am getting unexpected results. For example

```
MF = "IF(INDEX(CELL(\"width\",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,\"\",AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-"+readingsPerThirty+",COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))";
```

I have that Excel function stored as String, to be called later as such:

```
data.getRow(r+1).getCell(c,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellFormula(readings.get(r).getC(c));
```

Where data is a XSSFSheet

When the program runs the formula that actually entered into the cell is :

```
=@IF(@INDEX(CELL("width",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,"",AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))
```

I can not find any documentation or reports of where the @ symbols are coming from or what causes them. My question is why are they appearing and what can I do to prevent it. The @ causes Excel to have an error with a formula that works perfectly fine without them.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with `Excel 365` and the new functions which are normally prefixed with `_xlfn` in `Excel`'s file system storage.

Lets have a complete example to reproduce that issue:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class ExcelSetCellFormula {
 
 static final String WRONG = "IF(INDEX(CELL(\"width\",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,\"\",AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))";

 static final String CORRECT = "IF(INDEX(CELL(\"width\",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,\"\",_xlfn.AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx")); String filePath = "./ExcelNew.xlsx";
  Sheet data = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  int r = 0;
  int c = 4;
  data.getRow(r+1).getCell(c,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellFormula(WRONG);
  //data.getRow(r+1).getCell(c,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellFormula(CORRECT);
  System.out.println(data.getRow(r+1).getCell(c));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close() ;
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

The `Excel.xlsx` needs to have at least one worksheet having the rows 1 to 2 already. The code sets the formula in cell `E2`.

If the

```
static final String WRONG = "IF(INDEX(CELL(\"width\",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,\"\",AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))";
```

is set as the formula and you are opening the resulting `ExcelNew.xlsx` using `Excel 365` and you are trying to change the formula in `E2`, then you get the popup:

> Why is the @ operator here?
>
> We've upgraded Excel's Formula language
> and, as a result, you might notice the @ operator in some formulas.
> Your formulas will behave the same way they always have.

This refers to [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

But if we look closer, there is not even a reason to use that implicit intersection operator in that formula before `IF`. So why is it used?

The reason is that the new `AGGREGATE` function normally gets prefixed with `_xlfn.` in `Excel`s file system storage. But `Apache POI` is not doing this. So `Excel 365` interprets that function as user defined function while rendering and prefixes it with `_xludf.`. That's why the `#NAME?` error. And that's why the usage of implicit intersection operator `@` at all.

So if

```
static final String CORRECT = "IF(INDEX(CELL(\"width\",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),1)<6,\"\",_xlfn.AGGREGATE(4,5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))";
```

is set as the formula, where `AGGREGATE` is prefixed by `_xlfn.`, the `#NAME?` error disappears. And the implicit intersection operator `@` is not used by `Excel 365`.

Comment: Thank you! I wrapped my head about what was going on. The first noticeable change was the @ symbols, that I missed the _xlfn issue. I appreciate you. This was a well put answer and I hope that it helps others in the future!