# How to automatically remove @ of the excel formula generated by POI setCellFormula

Tags: apache-poi

When use setCellFormula set by paramete "CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)",but the output was "=@CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)", the @ symbol make the formula did not work and shows #VALUE in the result excel.
How can I remove the @ automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem as this one: [Apache POI Excel Formula entering @ Symbols where they don't belong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614172/apache-poi-excel-formula-entering-symbols-where-they-dont-belong/62619153#62619153).

All new functions (introduced after Excel 2007) are prefixed with `_xlfn` in internally file storage. The GUI does not show that prefix if the Excel version is able to interpret that function. If the Excel version is too old to be able to interpret that function you may see that prefix even in GUI.

Apache POI creates Excel files and that's why writes formulas in file storage directly. Using:

```java
cell.setCellFormula("CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)");
```

it writes `CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)` into the file storage but the Excel GUI expects `_xlfn.CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)`. That's why the `#NAME?`  error.

But why the `@`?  The `@` is the [implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). Implicit intersection is a new feature of Excel 365 (a silly one in my opinion, as well as dynamic array and spilling array behavior). And because Excel 365 does not know the function `CHISQ.TEST` without the prefix but it contains arrays of cells as parameters, it puts `@` in front of it to show that it would use implicit intersection if it would know it.

So the solution is to put the correct prefix before the function name in file storage to make it work:

```java
cell.setCellFormula("_xlfn.CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)");
```

Complete example to test:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;

class CreateExcelCHISQ_TEST {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   
   // Filling dummy data to another sheet
   Sheet otherSheet = workbook.createSheet("ChiSq_Data");
   row = otherSheet.createRow(4);
   row.createCell(3).setCellValue(123);
   row.createCell(4).setCellValue(456);
   row.createCell(5).setCellValue(78);
   row.createCell(11).setCellValue(122.5);
   row.createCell(12).setCellValue(456.5);
   row.createCell(13).setCellValue(77.5);
   
   row = sheet.createRow(0);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   //cell.setCellFormula("CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)"); // wrong
   cell.setCellFormula("_xlfn.CHISQ.TEST(ChiSq_Data!D5:F5,ChiSq_Data!L5:N5)");

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works but 1st time into the sheet it will show #VALUE!, and I I copy the cell to another cell and dorp the new added column, then the origianl  #VALUE! chnaged to the correct calculated result.

Comment: @ScorpJ: Are you talking about my complete example? If so, I cannot reproduce. My code is tested and works. If not, please ask a new question about this new issue and show a [minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @ScorpJ: [CHISQ.TEST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/chisq-test-function-2e8a7861-b14a-4985-aa93-fb88de3f260f) cannot return `#VALUE!`. It either returns a value or `#N/A`. So I suspect the `#VALUE!` is in the cell **before** you set the formula. Try forcing formula recalculation while opening using `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`.

Comment: @ScorpJ: Additional do check whether `ChiSq_Data!D5:F5` and `ChiSq_Data!L5:N5` contain numbers. If one of the cells contains the `#VALUE!` error, then each formula result from those cell ranges will result in `#VALUE!` too.