# Apache POI Excel Formula entering @ Symbols

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

i generate an excel document with my application.
I try to set a formula like this:

```
cell.setCellFormula("ANZAHL2(B10:B37");
```

What gets generated in my Excel-File is this:

```
=@ANZAHL2(B10:B37)
```

Where does the @-Symbol come from?

I have other cells where i just sum up different cell-values, and these work just fine

```
cell.setCellFormula("A5+A10");
```

gives me

```
=(A5+A10)
```

I found this thread
[Apache POI Excel Formula entering @ Symbols where they don't belong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614172/apache-poi-excel-formula-entering-symbols-where-they-dont-belong)
but the solution provided to put a '_xlfn.' in front of the aggregate-function doesnt work for me.

```
cell.setCellFormula("_xlfn.ANZAHL2(B10:B37");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Excel never stores localized formula strings.  It always stores en_US formula strings. So use `cell.setCellFormula("COUNTA(B10:B37)");` to make it work.

`Cell.setCellFormula` always sets the formula string as stored directly into the file.

The Excel GUI will change that formula to the German version `=ANZAHL2(B10:B37)` after it had read the en_US formula string from the file storage.